# Derivative of diagonal matrix with respect to vector composed of some elements of the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $n\times1$ vector $\vec{a}$ and $A=\mathrm diag(a)$. Let $\vec{a}_i$ $k\times 1$ subvector of $\vec{a}$ ($k<n$), given by the relation $\vec{a}=K\vec{a}_i$, where $K$ is an $n\times k$ matrix ($n,k\in\mathbb{N}$). I would like to compute the derivative $\dfrac{dA}{d\vec{a}_i}$.

Comment: What do you call a subvector?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I call a vector which consists of some elements of the other vector not in any particular order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find $\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{d\mathbf{a}_{\mathrm{i}}}$, notice that the
diagonal matrix $\mathbf{A}$ can mathematically be written as a function of
vector $\mathbf{a}$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathbf{a}\mathbf{e}_{\mathrm{i}}^{\mathrm{T}},
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{i}}$ an $n\times n$ matrix with all
its entries zero except for identity in $(i,i)$, and $\mathbf{e}_{\mathrm{i}}$
an $n\times1$ vector with identity on the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ element and zero everywhere else.
This derivative then becomes
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{d\mathbf{a}_{\mathrm{i}}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathbf{a}\mathbf{e}_{\mathrm{i}}^{\mathrm{T}}}{d\mathbf{a}_{\mathrm{i}}}=
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathbf{K}\mathbf{a}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathbf{e}_{\mathrm{i}}^{\mathrm{T}}}{d\mathbf{q}_{\mathrm{id}}}=
\sum_1^n\mathbf{e}_{\mathrm{i}}\otimes
\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathbf{K}\\=\sum_1^n\mathbf{I}_{n^2\times
n}(n(i-1)+i,i)\mathbf{K}=\mathbf{\Omega}\mathbf{K},
$$
where the matrix $\mathbf{\Omega}$ is constructed by adding ones in the
aformentioned slots $\forall i$, $1\leq i\leq n$ of the $n^2\times n$ matrix
$\mathbf{I}$.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many $A$'s in this question for my taste, so allow me to denote the subvector as $x$.  Then we have 
$$
  A = {\rm Diag}(Kx)
$$
the differential of which is
$$
  dA = {\rm Diag}(K\,dx)
$$
The derivative will be a $3^{rd}$ order tensor, so let's look at the derivative with respect to the $j^{th}$ component of $x$, which is merely a matrix
$$\eqalign{
  dA &= {\rm Diag}(Ke_j)\,dx_j \cr
     &= {\rm Diag}(k_j)\,dx_j \cr
  \frac{\partial A}{\partial x_j} &= {\rm Diag}(k_j) \cr
}$$
where $k_j$ is the $j^{th}$ column of $K$.